# Returning reference to a pointer- C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Consider the following class.

```
class mapping_items
{
public:

    mapping_items(){}

    void add(const mapping_item* item) {
        items_.push_back( item );
    }

    size_t count() const{
        return items_.size();
    }

    const mapping_item& find(const std::string& pattern){
        const mapping_item* item = // iterate vector and find item;
        return *item; 
    }

private:
    mapping_items(const mapping_items&); // not allowed
    mapping_items& operator=(const mapping_items&); // not allowed
    std::vector<const mapping_item*> items_;
};
```

C++ FAQ says,

> Use references when you can, and
>   pointers when you have to.

So in the above example, should I return `const mapping_item&` or `const mapping_item*` ?

The reason why I chose `mapping_item&` is because there will be always a default return value available. I will never have null returns. So a reference makes it clear that it can't have nulls. Is this the correct design?

Comment: Who owns (controls) the lifetime of the `mapping_item` objects?

Comment: It's this classes responsibility to clean it up. I have omitted destructor for making the code simple for posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem - what happens if your find() function fails? If this is expected never to happen, you are OK returning a reference (and raise an exception if it happens despite the fact it shouldn't). If on the other hand it may happen (e.g. looking up a name in an address book), you should consider returning  a pointer, as a pointer can be NULL, indicating the find failed.

Comment: `find` function will never fail. If it couldn't find an item matching the pattern, it returns a default item.

Comment: How is the default item managed? Presumably it is static in the class? If so, then returning a reference should be fine.

Comment: It's just another pointer points to a default `mapping_item` instance.

Comment: But who *creates* that default item? Is it initialized in the main code, exactly once? You didn't actually answer anon's question at all when they asked "how is the default item managed?" If you, for example, let find call "new mapping_items" to make a default object, that's a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

This is seems like an appropriate design choice to me - like the C++ FAQ states - uses references when you can.  IMO, unnecessary use of pointers just *seems* to make code harder to  understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the correct design. Clients can rely on values being non-null.

On a related note, some other class is responsible for managing the lifetime of mapping_item's?

Pointers and ownership easily introduces memory leaks or worse. You might want to consider whether you actually need to store pointers, or if you can get away with copying mapping_item's instead, to avoid memory leaks. However, pointers are necessary if you need to manage subclassed mapping_item's. Pointers are advisable if instances are large or need to be shared.

If you really need pointers, consider using boost::shared_ptr<> rather than raw pointers, both inside your class and as parameter types to e.g. the add() function.

Comment: This class will delete items in the vector. I have not shown the destructor in the code. Just to make it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will change the code to use shared_ptr.

Comment: BTW, this class is not part of public API. This is used internally and I am the only one who deals with it. So I know where to allocate and deallocate the objects. I am wondering is it worth using `shared_ptr` is such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Some people say, and I agree,

> use pointers if value can be `NULL`
>   and references otherwise

As to your example, I'd probably go for `return const mapping_item;`, so by value, to avoid having a reference to a temporary, and hope for my compiler to optimize copying away.

Comment: But `mapping_item` has got a vector which has `std::string`. So copying `mapping_item` by value will be costly. I have prevented it by providing private copy constructor and assignment operator.